# Rails model with many attributes (> 50 text fields) affect performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model `Account` and one of the `Account` objects is loaded for each request to the app.

The database call is cheap, as it caches it - so this is purely a Rails question.

If this model has say 50 or 100 text fields. Will that affect performance in anyway?

Comment: I think its the amount of memory that it eats up when you load the object( or perhaps objects) when you reference them

Comment: There are many dimensions to performance (search, retrieval of a record, adding a record, etc) so it would be helpful if you could be more specific in your question.  Inevitably, more work will impact performance in some level, the question is presumably whether it would degrade significantly.

Comment: @Snips I'm asking purely on the Rails side - and only loading object.  Nothing to do with database(retrieval/update/create) as the hit is negligible

Comment: Understood, but Rails plays a part in those too.  All the more reason to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

`Yes`, of course it will affect the performance. I'll suggest if you don't need all the 50 or 100 fields use `select` of `ActiveModel` to choose the column which is actually required

```
ModelName.select('field1, field2').where(<SOME CONDITION>)
```

Note:- This is useful if you required less fields (say 10 out of 50) present in your table.